# Trigger jQuery validation from address bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm currently writing a Coded UI Test and want to test my web frontend.
For this purpose i want to trigger the jQuery validation without having to click the submit button.
Is it possible to do this from the browsers address bar?
I already tried javascript:($('form').validate()) but this only gives me a blank page with "[object Object]"

Answer (score 0):

You can call the [valid()](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/) method to validate a form, given validator is already initialized for the form

```
$('form').valid()
```

Comment: This indeed validates the form and outputs true or false, but I'm searching for a way to get the same output as if i clicked the Save button (class input-validation-error added to the invalid input fields)